Next.js Site Not Indexing, Pages Found but Crawler Ignoring. Indexing problem
We're experiencing issues with Google not recognizing or indexing our pages despite everything appearing to be configured correctly. Here’s an overview of our setup and what we’ve tried so far:
Website Setup:
● Website Framework: Next.js
● Host: Vercel
● Domain: Cloudflare
● URL: https://studypdf.net
What We’ve Done:

SEO: All pages are optimized with proper meta tags, titles, and descriptions.
Page Speeds: Page loading speeds are good, no significant performance issues.
Indexing Requests: Submitting pages manually for indexing through Google Search Console works, and Google acknowledges these pages during submission.
Valid Hosting: Hosting and HTTPS configurations are valid.
Sitemap: Submitted and accessible at https://studypdf.net/sitemap.xml.

The Problem:
• Despite these steps, Google's crawler does not seem to recognize our pages consistently, leading to poor indexing results.
• We’ve recently updated our robots.txt to block unnecessary paths like _next and _vercel, but previously, these paths were not blocked and were accessible.

Out of 18 pages only one page is indexed which is our main page. we even edited our sitemap with priorities, and edited robots.txt to disallow chunks, clerks etc but no changes to indexing. we Don't know what's wrong.

But that doesn't seem to help. results are same,  no indexing.
Our Robots.txt Configuration:
User-agent: * 

Disallow: /_next/

Disallow: /_vercel/  

Disallow: /clerk/  

Disallow: /static/  

Disallow: /api/  

Disallow: /.well-known/  

Allow: /api/sitemap.xml

Sitemap: <https://studypdf.net/sitemap.xml>

Questions for the Community:

Impact of Blocking Paths: Could blocking directories like / _next, / _vercel, and others in the robots.txt file (which were previously accessible) be negatively affecting Google’s ability to crawl and index our pages? Could the blocking of chunks and static assets cause any indexing issues or will it helps us positively?

-Next.js & Vercel-Specific Configuration: Are there any specific configurations or best practices for Next.js or Vercel-hosted websites that we may have missed? Are there particular settings that could impact the indexing of dynamic content or static chunks?

Other Suggestions: Do you have any additional suggestions or insights that could help us resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Only you know whats in the directories you have blocked. You should therefore know if that blocks any access.
Also, if its a new site, you have to be patient and dont keep changing the structure. Updating content is good. It can take many months for a new site to be indexed fully.
Finally, it appears that you need to login to access other pages. Google cant index what it cant access. You can

Either recognise a robot crawl and give it access.
Or submit your url with a param, that gives Google access to those pages

